# SOAP with ksoap2

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I'm having problem when trying to call SOAP service from android. I google and I find out that i should be using ksoap2. So i installed that library and get some code...

```
 String METHOD_NAME = "name";
      String SOAP_ACTION = "url/name";
     String NAMESPACE = "url";
      String URL = "url";
    //you can get these values from the wsdl file^

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request
        request.addProperty("user", "user");
        request.addProperty("pass", "pass");
        //variable name, value. I got the variable name, from the wsdl file!
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); //put all required data into a soap envelope
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  //prepare request

        List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();

        headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
        headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("SoapAction", "url/name"));                   
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);  
        httpTransport.debug = true; 
        try {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerList);
            SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and it throws an exception in XmlPullParserException e2 called:

```
 org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@406da6b8)
```

So now i have no idea how to make it work. I think android has that really poorly managed because on iphone i get it to work in the matter of minutes.

Btw if it might help that's the envelope that should be used:

```
 <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>" +
            "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tns=\"url\" " +
            "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:wsdl=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/\" " +
            "xmlns:soap-enc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" >" +
            "<SOAP-ENV:Body><mns:name xmlns:mns=\"url\" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">" +
            "<user xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">user</user>" +
            "<pass xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">pass</pass>" +
            "</mns:name></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Any helkp would be appriciated because i'm trying to get this to work for quite some time now...

maybe that helps the expected result is like followed:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:MPListResponse><return xsi:type="xsd:string">[{"tip":"123456","stevilka":"123456789","key":"some value","zacetek":"01.05.2007","potek":"01.01.2018","axa":0},]</return></ns1:MPListResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

that's my httptransport request:

```
 Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><v:Header /><v:Body><n0:name id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="url"><user i:type="d:string">user</user><pass i:type="d:string">pass</pass></n0:MPList></v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

Comment: Which SOAP library are you using for your iPhone development?

Comment: I'm not using any library, i use NSMutableURLRequest and NSURLConnection and NSXMLParser, but i don't see how it helps me...

Comment: Use SoapUI utilite to check request/responce format. XmlPullParserException could appear if the responce is not xml too. Maybe server responces html with error. Anyway, please check androidHttpTransport.bodyOut in debug.

Comment: Apologies, it doesn't, it helps me, I hijacked your question.  However see my partial answer below about the use of wsdl2ksoap

Comment: ok it gets back an html but why? the response is as followed: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /MobileWS was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at url Port 443</address>
</body></html>

Comment: now i change somthings and i get thease back: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope//><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>Sender</faultcode><faultstring>Invalid XML</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: well now i get it to work, i make some stupid mistake, i get my xml to string now i have to parse it...

Comment: If you are using .net web service then please add this line to your code `envelope.dotNet = true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wsdl2ksoap](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2ksoap/) may help you here, followed by the use of the java SAXparser if your xml responses are not too long.  At least that's the approach I have taken with success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your SOAP Envelop version is wrong. Try to change it. It's works for me.

```
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
```